# Rails 3.2 + Heroku + S3 + CloudFront: Not serving gzip css js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

I am running Rails 3.2 with assets_sync.

A gz version of my css and js are created. CloudFront is not serving the gzip version even though the header requested for gzip,deflate.

I also tried `config.gzip_compression = true` in `asset_sync.rb` but CloudFront is still serving the uncompressed version. I have confirmed that I can access `ABC.cloudfront.net/XYZ.css.gz`

Comment: config.gzip_compression = true actually does it's job. It replaces files with their gzipped version so CloudFront will always serve compressed version. You most likely to have caching issue, try rename your file. (or be sure you have digests on your filenames and file contents changed)

Answer (score 4):

Is the origin for your CloudFront distribution an S3 bucket? If so, the problem is that S3 doesn't handle the `Accept-Encodings` header correctly: https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync/issues/153

There are some potential solutions outlined in that issue. You can either serve gzipped files by default, since most browsers (excluding some mobile browsers) will handle it correctly, or you con try the [solution outlined here](http://code.dblock.org/serving-compressed-rails-assets-from-s3-via-cloudfront).

Another possible solution is to use a Varnish cache layer as the custom origin for your CloudFront distribution:

**Internet -> CloudFront -> Varnish -> S3 Bucket**

As a request comes in to CloudFront, it will be forwarded to Varnish if it hasn't been cached in CloudFront, yet. Varnish will grab the uncompressed file from the S3 Bucket, compress it as the headers dictate, and send the file back to CloudFront for caching.

Comment: Is your asset_sync.rb located in config/initializers?

Have you ensured you're not getting this line in your rails log?

"AssetSync: using default configuration from built-in initializer"

Comment: I ended up dropping the S3 part and serving directly to cloudfront, but your answer makes a lot of sense. Have a bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you set `heroku config:add ASSET_SYNC_GZIP_COMPRESSION=true` for your application?